# Mutability of an Object

Tags: scala

Martin Odersky gave the Keynote talk for Scala Days 2013.

One slide was titled "[When is an Object Mutable](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter32/about)?" Its contents read as follow:

```
class Memo[T, U](fn: T => U) {

  val memo = new mutable.WeakHashMap[T, U]
  def apply(x: T) = memo.getOrElseUpdate(x, fn(x))
}

// an object is mutable if its (functional) behavior depends on its history

new Memo {i: Int => i + 1} // immutable

var ctr = 0;
new Memo { i: Int => ctr += i; ctr } // mutable
```

Please explain why the Memo examples are, respectively, immutable and mutable.

Comment: This article gives a very useful view on the matter which might help clear up the confusion: http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2012/09/13/what-purity-is-and-isnt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the provided function increments given value by 1. The result does not depend on any external state.

In the second example the result depends on `ctr` value that is some global state in relation to `Memo`. In other words, the global state, represented by `ctr` value, can influence the behavior and the result in the second example.

Comment: Does its mutability change if ctr is private? Or no since its value can still change?

Comment: @Kevin As long as `ctr` can change irrespectively from `Memo` and the provided function, the behavior of the second example is mutable, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

> In some cases, an object is considered immutable even if some internally-used attributes change but the object's state appears to be unchanging from an external point of view. For example, an object that uses memoization to cache the results of expensive computations could still be considered an immutable object.

But I'd like to draw the attention to "*could* [...] be considered", so *not everyone* considers it to be immutable.

If you look at this Memo implementation using an immutable Map:

```
class Memo[T, U](val fn: T => U, map: Map[T, U]) {
  def this(fn: T => U) {
    this(fn, Map[T, U]())
  }

  def apply(x: T): (U, Memo[T, U]) = {
    if (map.contains(x)) {
      println("Cache hit")
      (map(x), this)
    } else {
      println("Cache miss")
      val result = fn(x)
      val newMap = map + ((x, result))
      (result, new Memo(fn, newMap))
    }
  }
}
```

there is no mutable internal state at all (it's delegated to the caller). But now we have the problem to differ between two degrees of immutability.

From a practical point of view, a memoizer must be *functional*, but its name/purpose implies mutability, even if it does not affect external behaviour.